# java 8 lambda recursion failing

Tags: java, recursion, lambda, subdirectory

I am trying to use lambda to recursively go through a directory and every sub directory while pushing each sub directory to a new thread.

The problem is that it is making it through the top level directory and the
all of the first round of sub directory, yet is refusing to dive into any of the sub directories that are within the first level of sub directories.

I do not understand why it is working for the first level of recursion but not for the second level. Is there a limit to how many times you can nest a thread and/or lambda function?

Here is the relevant part of my code below:

```
public class Main
{
    public static ExecutorService localExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    public static void getFileNames(final Path dir)
    {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir))
        {
            for (Path path : stream) {
                System.out.println(path);

                if (path.toFile().isDirectory()) {
                    Runnable subDir = () -> getFileNames(path);

                    localExecutor.submit(subDir);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        getFileNames(
            FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\A")
        );
         //
     //I wait for it to finish all tasks in another method that contains the below

        functions.localExecutor.shutdown();
        try {
        functions.localExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.print("Exception: the following error occured: ");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            MainLogic.log.add("Exception: the following error occured: " +     e.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) variables should be lower camel case `LocalExecutor` -> `localExecutor`. 2) you don't need braces around your lambda. `Runnable subDir = () -> getFileNames(path,i,directory);` is fine 3) don't mix arrays and `List`s

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging it? Like line breaks, print statements etc.? Your code is not complete. There's a missing catch, no return and not enough closing braces.

Comment: Are you certain you are waiting long enough? You may wish to capture the `Future` returned by `submit` in a list and wait until they are all complete. Alternatively you could call `shutdown` on the `ExecutorService` to wait for it to complete processing.

Comment: @Michael - The missing `catch` is because of the `try(DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir))` which is a *try-with-resources* clause which will close the resource automagically.

Comment: I have print statements on my code, and that is what is telling me what level it is successfully getting down to. I just pasted the non debugging code because I identified which part isn't being fired, and when.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon It is try-with-resources but `newDirectoryStream` throws `IOException` which is a checked exception that needs a catch block (or the method signature should change).

Comment: I've changed your example to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For what it's worth, it Works On My Machine™

Comment: Not an expert in the ```ExecutorService``` api... but it seems that you are assuming that this task would eventually be executed... after executing this code, is your program waiting long enough for those tasks to be run?

Comment: I have found that adding a .get to catch the future returned does make the code work, but this makes the code sequential, not parallel.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your program does not wait for those subtasks to be executed. It just returns immediately. So only the first level directory are printed out since those println do not depend on any such subdir runnable to be executed.

Typically one can call `ExecutorService`'s `shutdown` and `awaitTermination`, to wait for any pending task to run. However this would not work in your case since deeper directory level's corresponding task are not added until later on when their parent dir's task has been executed.

Comment: the code `public static void main(String... args)
    {
        getFileNames(
            FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\A")
        );
    }`
will never wait for termination of the async threads as explained above the main method above terminates before the async threads have completed.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my question to fully reflect what my code is doing for this part. It is waiting like demonstrated in the revised question, but still not working for 2nd level sub directories. it works for first level directories and first sub level directories but once it gets to second level sub directories a.k.a folder/folder/folder, it stops working. Yet it works for folder/folder and folder

Comment: @phalanx as explained in the second paragraph the way you are waiting won't ever work, once you invoke shutdown, no new task will be permitted so you only will get println of the top directory and the first level subdirectories names. I have never code one myself so I cannot advice how exactly ... but you might want to try to create a ```Spliterator``` that would produce a parallelizable stream through all subdirectories.

Comment: But I am confused how this can be the case because I am not being hit by any executor terminated errors, which happen if a new task is pushed to a closed executor.

Comment: @phalanx I see your point. Since you are just printing the exceptions stack trace there is a chance that these are lost (i mean it is not shown to you in the output) if somehow you are redirecting the output somewhere. You can try just not to catch them to see if that makes your program stop even earlier.

Comment: @phalanx... actually try to stop the VM in the catch all together.... since they are running in separate threads a non-catch may actually be just silent... System.exit(1)

Comment: i switched from submit to execute and that made me get hit with the executor terminated error, so I assume you all are correct in that the non catch was just being silent.

Comment: @phalanx good to know, at least we know for sure what the problem is.... I think the way to go is probably coding your own Spliterator or perhaps someone has done the job already.... once is a stream then you can just unleash Stream parallelism.